# Limit same data entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im new to sql and i have two tables, one for fridges and one for food. Only 5 items of food can be stored into one fridge, so i was wondering if there is a way to limit the food table to only have 5 of the same fridge_id entries?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to enforce such a constraint.

The best I can think of is:

- have a (redundant) column `food_count` on the fridges table
- define an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` trigger on the food table that updates `food_count` whenever something changes
- add a check constraint on the fridges table that limits `food_count` to 5

Comment: I agree that this is typically the best method for this type of constraint.